# Get MONTH NAME from date in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract the MONTH NAME from a date in BigQuery, the type is DATE (i.e., 2019-09-19). I tried something like:

> SELECT PARSE_DATE('%B',CAST(date_start AS string)) FROM table

but it doesn't work. I also tried some other stuff from the [DATE funcs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) such as `EXTRACT` and the [DATETIME funcs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions) with no luck.

I know there are some functions like `MONTHNAME()` in other SQL languages, but they don't work in BQ.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't rely in CASE function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the documentation you need to use the [FORMAT_DATETIME function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime). The query would look as the following:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME("%B", DATETIME(<your_date_column_name>)) as month_name
FROM <your_table>
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported-format-elements-for-date) you'll find all the parameters you can use in order to display certain information about the date.

Comment: Works! I don't know how I missed that, I've been trying it for a while now!

Gracias Miguel!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I was able to help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to extract the MONTH NAME from a date in BigQuery, the type is DATE (i.e., 2019-09-19)

As your field is already of DATE type - You don't need to do any extra casting - just:

```
FORMAT_DATE('%B', date_start)
```

will work - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-09-19' date_start
)
SELECT date_start, FORMAT_DATE('%B', date_start) AS month
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row date_start  month    
1   2019-09-19  September
```